# Internet is slow and intermittent connectivity, but running ping in windows command prompt displays "General Failure"

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, command-line, internet, ping

When browsing the web on my Dell Optiplex 7010 running Windows 10, the internet is somewhat slow and sometimes even cuts out for a while. Running an internet test, it says that my download is over 80, but it doesn't feel like that. I ran the `ping` command in windows command prompt and it replied with "General Failure".

[image: screenshot of ping]

I can still connect to webpages, but the internet cuts out a lot.

Sometimes the Network window displays "No Wireless Connection", and when I run the Windows Network Troubleshooter, It says there is a problem with the network adapter and fixes it. Could this be a hardware problem?

How can I fix this? Is it a software or hardware problem?

Answer (score 2):

#### Is it a software or hardware problem?

There is not enough information to diagnose hardware vs software.

To rule out a software issue try completely reinitialising all network states.

Run the following commands in an elevated (run as administrator) `cmd` shell:

- Reset WINSOCK entries to installation defaults (reboot required):

  `netsh winsock reset catalog`
- Reset TCP/IP stack to installation defaults:

  `netsh int ip reset reset.log`
- Reset Firewall to installation defaults:

  `netsh advfirewall reset`
- Flush DNS resolver cache:

  `ipconfig /flushdns`
- Renew DNS client registration and refresh DHCP leases:

  `ipconfig /registerdns`
- Flush routing table (reboot required):

  `route /f`

Comment: What does elevated cmd shell mean?

Comment: Run as administrator

Comment: When I reset the ICP/IP stack, It says Access Denied, when resetting the Resolve Neighbor.

https://imgur.com/a/TJHzlWh

Comment: Also, Sometimes the Network window displays "No Wireless Connection", and when I run the Windows Network Troubleshooter, It says there is a problem with the network adapter and fixes it. Could this be a hardware problem?

Comment: "What does elevated cmd shell mean?" :- search for cmd  on the start menu, then right click on the result and select run as administrator

Answer (score 0):

Run the following commands(elevated -> search cmd into start menu and right click and select run as administrator ) and post result on here, You need to  isolate the  problem whether its related to **connectivity** (wifi signal strength , type netsh wlan show interfaces into cmd ) , **routing** issue (type traceroute google.com into cmd), or a **dns lookup** issue (type nslookup google.com).

Update :So far it looks good , but we need more info.
Could you run two programs

- (1) LatencyMon from http://www.resplendence.com/download/LatencyMon.exe , install & run program ,press green arrow , then use your pc with the internet, post screenshot(main & stat pages) of program until the next error from the adapter (adapter not a available).Run ping -t google.com in cmd prompt (background it) also .
- (2)  Homedale wifi scanner https://www.the-sz.com/common/get.php?product=homedale , click the access  point tab to switch tabs, now right click on any of the sub tabs and unselect mac address , vendor signal strength history ,encryption and country id .Make sure frequency tab is visible.Run for 10minutes and post the screenshot here.

Comment: I have posted the results in an answer

Comment: Cool , new instructions updated in my edit

Answer (score 0):

Here are the results for binaryOps20:

[image]

[image]

[image]